# JavaScript access object

Tags: javascript, json

How can I get the "name" of the following JSON object?

```
 "location": {
    "name": "Hilden",
    "country": "Germany",
    "region": "Nordrhein-Westfalen",
    "lat": "51.167",
    "lon": "6.933",
    "timezone_id": "Europe/Berlin",
    "localtime": "2020-04-22 15:03",
    "localtime_epoch": 1587567780,
    "utc_offset": "2.0"
}
```

```
["name"] returns the followin error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Comment: `.name`? `["name"]`? Once you've parsed it it's just a *JavaScript* object, you access its properties as you would any other.

Comment: that aint be workin: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: *"aint be workin"*?! What did you try to access that property on then? [Edit] to give a [mre], and please write in a more professional manner when you do so.

Comment: i did this:
 weather["location"]["name"]

Comment: The object you're showing doesn't have a `location` prop, so it's unclear why you thought that *would* work.

Comment: it has. here be the hole json:
{
  "request": {
    "type": "City",
    "query": "Hilden, Germany",
    "language": "en",
    "unit": "m"
  },
  "location": {
    "name": "Hilden",
    "country": "Germany",
    "region": "Nordrhein-Westfalen",
    "lat": "51.167",
    "lon": "6.933",
    "timezone_id": "Europe/Berlin",
    "localtime": "2020-04-22 14:58",
    "localtime_epoch": 1587567480,
    "utc_offset": "2.0"
  }

Comment: Again, [edit] the question. Give a [mre] that allows others to recreate the issue. But basically you use either dot or bracket notation per my first comment, and there's no utility to SO to have yet another *"but how do I use basic JavaScript on **this** object?"*

Comment: sorry pro :))))))))

Comment: What you've now posted is *not* a [mre], because it's not syntactically valid JSON or JavaScript and doesn't actually illustrate the problem. Please review [ask] and update your question, but I won't spend further time on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access its properties using location.name, location["name"], for example:

```
const location = {
  "name": "Hilden",
  "country": "Germany",
  "region": "Nordrhein-Westfalen",
  "lat": "51.167",
  "lon": "6.933",
  "timezone_id": "Europe/Berlin",
  "localtime": "2020-04-22 14:44",
  "localtime_epoch": 1587566640,
  "utc_offset": "2.0"
}

location.name;
location.["name"]
```

If you want to use it from the JSON object:

```
var y = '{"location": { "name": "Hilden", "country": "Germany", "region": "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "lat": "51.167", "lon": "6.933", "timezone_id": "Europe/Berlin", "localtime": "2020-04-22 15:03", "localtime_epoch": 1587567780, "utc_offset": "2.0" }}';


JSON.parse(y).location.name
```

So, in this case, you should use JSON.parse(jsonObject)) before access its properties. BUT NOTICE: "Make sure the text is written in JSON format, or else you will get a syntax error.", a "large text" inside {} - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Answer (score 1):

This could help you if not then let me know. If your json object is same as your_json_obj then you have to parse it first using JSON.parse(your_json_obj). If not then you simply use `your_json_obj.location.name`

```
const your_json_obj = "{
"location": {
    "name": "Hilden",
    "country": "Germany",
    "region": "Nordrhein-Westfalen",
    "lat": "51.167",
    "lon": "6.933",
    "timezone_id": "Europe/Berlin",
    "localtime": "2020-04-22 15:03",
    "localtime_epoch": 1587567780,
    "utc_offset": "2.0"
},
...}"
const name = JSON.parse(your_json_obj).location.name
console.log(name)
```